# how to check whether geo replication exists for a db in azure server using arm cmdlets

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database

Does anyone know to check whether geo replication exists for a db in azure server using arm cmdlets?

I tried

`Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseGeoBackup` is not giving proper result.

```
database : db in r1 group in server s1.
```

I need to create a geo replication in r2 group in s2 server

Comment: The shift key is that big key on either side of your keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

To find the geo-replication secondaries for a database use

```
Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseReplicationLink.
```

For more information see, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.sql/v2.3.0/get-azurermsqldatabasereplicationlink.

`Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseGeoBackup` returns the geo-redundant backup for a database enabling you to restore from it to create a new database, which is not what you want (as you found).

Answer (score 0):

Adding non readable secondary:

```
$database = Get-AzureRmSqlDatabase –DatabaseName "mydb" -ResourceGroupName "rg1" -ServerName "srv1"
$secondaryLink = $database | New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseSecondary –PartnerResourceGroupName "rg2" –PartnerServerName "srv2" -AllowConnections "No"
```

Adding readable secondary:

```
$database = Get-AzureRmSqlDatabase –DatabaseName "mydb" -ResourceGroupName "rg1" -ServerName "srv1"
$secondaryLink = $database | New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseSecondary –PartnerResourceGroupName "rg2" –PartnerServerName "srv2" -AllowConnections "All"
```

[Further reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-geo-replication-powershell).

Comment: How does this help

Comment: Well, if you would be reading the question it says: `I need to create a geo replication in r2 group in s2 server`

Comment: yes,but the question is `Does anyone know to check whether geo replication exists for a db in azure server using arm cmdlets?`...he wants to finally do create based on whether replication exists or not

Comment: again, if you would follow the link, it describes a way to find that out

Comment: I think adding that will help question

Comment: well, I guess it doesn't make sense now, as there is a second answer in place.